# Is it valid to check the component state in an event function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, flux

I am using react and have a component with the `listChanged` function, called after a Store change event :

```
getInitialState: function () {
    return {
        isLive: true,
        data: [],
    };
},

componentDidMount: function() {  
    MyStore.addChangeListener(this.listChanged);
},

listChanged: function() {
    if (this.state.isLive) {
        var data = MyStore.getData();
        var newState = {
            data: data
        };

        this.setState(newState);
    }
},

pause: function(e) {
    this.state.isLive = !this.state.isLive;
},
```

and I have a button that switches the `isLive` state by calling the `pause` function. This is working since I have a visual cue bound to that variable and I also confirmed with React Debug Extension for Google Chrome (in the React tab for my component).

Is it legal to check that variable in such a function responding to an event? The function threats my isLive state as true because my state data is always refreshed no matter the variable value. But I visually confirmed that this variable is set to false...

**TLDR : even if the `this.state.isLive` variable is set to `false`, the `this.setState(newState);` is still called in the `listChanged` function.**

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in a fiddle? (Use the [React Base Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/reactjs/69z2wepo/).)

Comment: @Jordan I tried to start but it is difficult, I need all the classes for Actions, Dispatcher and all of their dependencies for events...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's completely valid. This, however, is not:

```
pause: function(e) {
    this.state.isLive = !this.state.isLive;
},
```

You cannot set a state value this way. You *must* use `setState`:

```
pause: function(e) {
    this.setState({ isLive: !this.state.isLive });
},
```

Comment: hum thanks! Fixed it, however it did not fix my problem :(